# Algolia - InstantSearchHelper

Tags: android, algolia

I'm following the tutorial on how to implement Algolia into an Android app.
[Tutorial](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/getting-started/android/#build-the-user-interface-and-display-your-data-hits)

the line:

```
Searcher searcher = Searcher.create(ALGOLIA_APP_ID, ALGOLIA_SEARCH_API_KEY, ALGOLIA_INDEX_NAME);
helper = new InstantSearchHelper(this, searcher);
helper.search();
```

Keeps giving me this error:

```
Cannot resolve symbol ‘InstantSearchHelper’
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem but after some research, just remove "Helper":

`InstantSearch helper = new InstantSearch(this, searcher);`